# Finding x and y offset of point after rotation

Tags: math, game-physics, trigonometry

Hi so I'm stuck with a problem. My old projectile system would only shoot in 4 directions so when finding a new offset it was easy, I just had to inverse certain numbers

```
           case "down":
                xOffset = hitbox.xOffset;
                yOffset = hitbox.yOffset;
                width = hitbox.width;
                height = hitbox.height;
                break;
            case "up":
                xOffset = hitbox.xOffset;
                yOffset = -hitbox.yOffset - hitbox.height;
                width = hitbox.width;
                height = hitbox.height;
                break;
            case "right":
                xOffset = hitbox.yOffset;
                yOffset = hitbox.xOffset;
                width = hitbox.height;
                height = hitbox.width;
                break;
            case "left":
                xOffset = -hitbox.yOffset - hitbox.height;
                yOffset = hitbox.xOffset;
                width = hitbox.height;
                height = hitbox.width;
                break;
```

So this worked perfectly, but now the problem is I am no longer using rects for my hitbox and using circles, and i also now implemented 360 shooting.

I have a function that gets the x and y speed based on where I clicked but I do not have the function to get the new hitbox based on it.

```
  newSpeed.x += speed * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
  newSpeed.y += speed * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);
```

How can I do something similar to get the new offset?

Comment: which language is that?

Comment: What do you need for the hitbox? You said you are using circles now, so don't you just need a position and a radius? Please explain your system in more detail (possibly with an image) - we can't guess how it looks like.